# Assign two actions to a VIM shortcut

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the following keyboard shortcut in VIM

```
nnoremap C vi"
```

This enable me to select text between "" by clicking `C`.

Now I want this same shortcut, to do the same but for ''.

```
nnoremap C vi'
```

Putting these two rules doesn't work, as the last replaces the one before it.

Is there a way to make both of them work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need to build the intelligence into the mapping. This can be done via a `:help :map-expr`:

```
nnoremap <expr> C 'vi' . (getline('.') =~ '"' ? '"'  : "'")
```

This simplistic example will check whether the current line contains a double quote, and then select those, else single quotes. For a useful mapping, you probably need to ensure surrounding quotes on both sides (using `search()`), and if both types match select the "closer" one. With a `:function`, you can make that as complex as you like...

Comment: Perfect answer. Period.